# How to achieve apple achievement badge screen in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, meta

I need to develop a feature in my application which shows one badge icon like the one apple watch application shows where we can rotate the badge. Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?[image]

Comment: What do you mean by rotating in three dimensions? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, so please update your question. Do you have any code yet?

Comment: means we can move the badge from left to right by touching the icon like we used to do in apple watch application. I haven't coded because I'm confused which one to use currently I'm having one 3d object model.